# Why this move constructor is so greedy?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo_class {
    std::string value;
public:
    foo_class(const foo_class& v) : value{v.value} {
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    foo_class(foo_class&& v) : value{std::move(v.value)} {
        std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~foo_class() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    foo_class(std::string v) : value{std::move(v)} {
        std::cout << "type constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Data {
    foo_class a;
    foo_class b;
};

int main() {
    std::string c = "3";
    Data x{c,c+"3"};
    return 0;
}
```

**IMPORTANT**, I compile it with GCC and Clang (4.8.2 and 3.4 respectively) and the flag **-fno-elide-constructors**, so we don't elide the copy/move constructors.

The result of the execution is the following one:

```
type constructor
move constructor
destructor
type constructor
move constructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
```

Which means that the copy constructor is not being used at all, even when it should be used for the first argument of the constructor of the struct Data.

Next, If I delete the copy constructor, the code is still legal according to my compilers, but in my understanding should be illegal, cause I'm not casting to && (using std::move) when passing the first argument of the constructor of Data.

My question is simple: 
**Why is this happening? 
Am I missing something?**

Comment: Why do you think it should be a copy? Both arguments go through conversion, so you've got two temporaries that can be moved.

Comment: Does it mean that I couldn't achieve perfect forwarding to std::string value without declaring a forwarding constructor in Data?

Comment: "Perfect Forwarding" is a concept that applies to template functions, which you don't have.  Your code moves the contents of the strings directly to `x`, which is the same thing a set of perfect forwarding functions would do though. Though you do have one extra copy in your type constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Because the `foo_class` objects constructed in

```
Data x{c,c+"3"};
```

are both temporaries. So they invoke *move* constructor instead of *copy* constructor.

```
type constructor // 1. Construct a temporary foo_class object out of string "c" for a
move constructor // 2. Move the temporary object created above to x.a
destructor       // 3. Destruct the temporary foo_class object created in 1
type constructor // 4. Same as 1, but the object is for b, and the string "33"
move constructor // 5. Same as 2, moved to x.b
destructor       // 6. Destruct the temporary foo_class object created in 4
destructor       // 7. Destruct x.b
destructor       // 8. Destruct x.a
```